# Build up dynamic table joins in JOOQ

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I am using JOOQ as a SQL builder tool to then execute in a jdbcTemplate. I need to dynamically add table joins to the from clause. At the moment I am doing it like this..

```
SelectJoinStep<?> selectClause = select(field("ColumnA"), field("ColumnB"))
.from(table("TableA"));

if(condition) {
  selectClause.join(table("TableB), JoinType.JOIN).on(field("columnA").eq(field("columnB")));
}
```

Then I combine the select clause with the where clause..

```
org.jooq.Query ps = selectClause.where(whereClause);
```

This works ok but now I want to introduce paging so I need to swap out the selected fields for a simple count and it would be good if I could reuse the from clause in this count query but I can't because the select and from clause are in the same variable.

Update..
Why can I not build up the from clause dynamically like so...

```
    List<Field<?>> fields = new ArrayList<Field<?>>();
    fields.add(...);
    Table<?> from = table("TableA");
    if(condition) {
      from.join(table("TableB), JoinType.JOIN).on(field("columnA").eq(field("columnB")));
    }
org.jooq.Query ps = select(fields).from(from);
```

If condiiton is true table join does not appear in generated SQL?

Comment: *"I am using JOOQ as a SQL builder tool to then execute in a jdbcTemplate"* - Why not execute with jOOQ directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach to using jOOQ for dynamic SQL is [a more functional approach](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/01/16/a-functional-programming-approach-to-dynamic-sql-with-jooq/). Don't think in terms of "swapping out" parts of your query under certain conditions. Think in terms of what parts of your query are provided by whom through functions? For example:

```
ResultQuery<?> query(
    Supplier<Collection<SelectField<?>>> select,
    boolean condition,
    boolean paginate
) {
    Condition whereClause = ...;
    Table<?> from = table("TableA");
    if (condition)
        from = from.join(table("TableB")).on(field("ColumnA").eq(field("ColumnB")));

    return select(select.get())
          .from(from)
          .where(whereClause)
          .limit(paginate ? 10 : Integer.MAX_VALUE); // Could be done differently
}
```

Now call the above:

```
query(() -> Arrays.asList(field("ColumnA"), field("ColumnB")), true, true);
query(() -> Arrays.asList(count()), true, false);
```

Of course, another option would be to use a window function to calculate that count value, instead of running two queries:

```
count().over()
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer and I will explore this approach but could you look at my update above.

Comment: @jonesy: Please look very closely how I wrote this. `Table.join()` is not a mutating operation. You have to re-assign the result table to your local variable.